# JQuery XML Selectors issue

Tags: jquery, xml, css-selectors

I am building a webpage that loads new 'pages' by loading XML files and then changing the content. The issue I am having is that when the data is loaded, the selectors are not working. The error occurs when I load a gallery. Each image has a class "thumbs". The image loads fine, but the $("thumbs").click() code in my js does not work. Is there some issue with that object being loaded that would cause jquery to not find it when looking for selectors?

Comment: If you add the click handlers before the content is loaded you would need to use event delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the class-selector code, specifically, the dot: `.`.  Change your click event to this:

```
$(".thumbs").click();
```

And it should work, though, if this content is loaded dynamically, you will need to use the .on() method as others have mentioned:

```
$(".container_class").on('click',".thumbs",function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some issue with that object being loaded that would cause
>   jquery to not find it when looking for selectors?

Yes.
It sounds like you are loading the new 'pages' dynamically, is that right?  If so, the selector you have there will not work because the targeted elements did not exist at the time of its execution.  Try using a more dynamic-friendly `on()` method instead:

`$(".thumbs").on('click',function(e){})`

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm, and now makes more sense. I was really hoping I would have to restructure the whole site! You saved my day.